# How can i order my posts by post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, post-type

i have a query post :

```
$args3 = array(
    'posts_per_page'=>20,
    'post_type'=>array('num1','num2'),
    's' => urldecode($command),
    'orderby'   => 'type',
    'order' => 'ASC'
    );
query_posts($args3);
```

i want in result first show `num1` post type results before `num2` . what should i do ?

Comment: if i use 2 query i must use a lot of codes for limit number of posts but with 1 query i know how many post will show in result.
in wordpress codex : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters
there is a line for order by post type but there is no example...

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution for your prob dude

```
add_filter( 'posts_request' , 'modify_request' );
function modify_request( $query) {
    global $wpdb;
    if(strstr($query,"post_type IN ('review', 'directory')")){
        $where = str_replace("ORDER BY {$wpdb->posts}.post_date","ORDER BY {$wpdb->posts}.post_type",$query);
    }
    return $where;
}
```